# "Back button" using getSupportActionbar and appcompat v7 toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm using the new toolbar from the Appcompat V7 library and I'm making an application with navigation drawer and with fragments.

In some fragments I don't want to show the hamburger icon but the arrow instead... That is fine I did this in this way:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

mDrawerToggle.syncState();
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
```

My question is that: How or where i need to set up the home button lisener or what i need to listen for the "back" button ? 
I want to call the main backpressed method and to set back the navigation drawer icon with the hamburger icon..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    setUpNavigationDrawer();

    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(backStackListener); // listen to the backstack of the fragment manager
}
```

Define the onBackSTackChangedListener:

```
private FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener backStackListener = new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onBackStackChanged() {
       setNavIcon();
   };
}
```

Set the icon according to your fragment's backstack:

```
protected void setNavIcon() {
    int backStackEntryCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(backStackEntryCount == 0);
}
```

Detect when the drawer icon is pressed:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled() && drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case x:
         return true;
      default:
         return false;
    }
}
```

And handle the up button:

```
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

This works for me. Good luck.

Comment: What's `case x` supposed to be?

Comment: @tanneebee : how to receive back arrow click?

Answer (score 71):

Add this method in `onCreate()`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then override the `onOptionItemSelected()` as below:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Not sure if this works in OP's case, but in many cases this is probably the simplest option to implement Back button with the AppCompat Toolbar.

Skip all the `setHomeButtonEnabled`, `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` and `onOptionsItemSelected` stuff, and [related issues](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2ox3s6/appcompat_toolbar_back_button_functionality_on/).

Instead, when initialising the Toolbar, simply set 1) navigation icon and 2) navigation OnClickListener for it:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if (enableBackNavigation) {
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't stop swipe from edge to pull the navigation drawer

Answer (score 16):

1- Create `Toolbar` layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

2- Include this in your layout at the place where you want the `toolbar` to be.

3- Paste the following code in your activity.(extends `ActionBarActivity`)

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;

//For Toolbar (Action bar) start
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Event Details");
        //For Toolbar (Action bar) end
```

4- change the back click icon to whatever you want.

Comment: This is a very clear, easy to understand, efficient and reusable solution. I would have done it the same way! Well done! ;)

Answer (score 3):

activate the back button:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(enable);
```

and listen for clicks in `onBackPressed()`

Obviously your activity must extend `ActionBarActivity`

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can set Navigation icon and make sure you are setting `setNavigationOnClickListener()` after setting `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back));
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in manifest add these lines under the activity you want the back arrow working

> android:parentActivityName="Your parent activity name"

Answer (score 0):

Add setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

```
    Toolbar toolbar  = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Handle the back button

```
   public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```