# How to make the screen orientation faster in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, orientation

I am having two layout in my application one is (landscape mode) and the second one in (portrait) mode whenever i click the button in first layout to second as well as from second to first it takes time to load the layout.cananyone tell me how i can make the screens to be displayed faster when orientation is done.

Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".farmer.activity.Farmertrade_Activity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".farmer.activity.FarmerLedgerView_Activity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Android system automatically handles configuration change events and restarts the current activity with the new configuration.so we can not increase speed of configuration changes.

However  the application displayed a lot of data automatic destruction/creation of the activities life cycle can be take more time.

Comment: can you tell me how to highlight a backbutton in toolbar bcoz i tap it twice it again reloads the same activity

Comment: i don't have more data in the application

Comment: refer @ Raja Jawahar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230827/back-button-using-getsupportactionbar-and-appcompat-v7-toolbar